# DataTables AJAX dynamic URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I want to create a general function to initialise all my ajax DataTables.

I need to be able to identify the table that is requesting data so my server-side script knows which data to send back.

I thought I'd simply be able to attach the table ID to the ajax URL like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "www.example.com/load-" + this.id + ".php"
        }
    });
});
```

I thought the URL would resolve to "www.example.com/load-example.php" but it didn't work as `this.id` is undefined (as is `$(this).attr('id')`) so I thought maybe I could use a single server-side script and pass in an extra $_GET parameter like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            url: "www.example.com/load-table.php",
            data: function ( d ) {
                d.experiment = this.id;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This also failed for the same reason.

Is it possible to get the table ID when retrieving data this way?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution that works but if someone has a better way, please post your solution here.

This solution binds to any table that has the class 'data-table'.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.data-table').each(function(index) {
        var table = this.id;
        $(this).DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "www.example.com/load-" + table + ".php"
            }
        });
    });
});
```